# Checking visibility of an element in a specific div, Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 3 `div`s with the same class and inside other `div`s when sometimes the class `pak` is visible and sometimes it's not.

I want to check if the class `pak` is visible on the first `div`.

Do I have any way to check if class is exist on a specific element when there is other elements that contains exactly the same class?

```
<div class='ra22'>
    <div class='poko'></div>
</div>
<div class='ra22'>
    <div class='poko pak'></div>
</div>
<div class='ra22'>
    <div class='poko pak'></div>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried to do:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ra22 .pak)))
except:
    print 'class ".pak" not visible'
```

and of course the `WebDriver` find the class on the second `div`.

Is there a solution on how can I search the class `pak` only in the first `div`?

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the _outerHTML_

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ra22 .pak")
# then you can check visibility of every element fron the list
```

If you want to check the current state of element do this:

```
if elements[0].is_displayed(): # checks first element
  print "Element visible"
else:
  print "Element not visible"
```

if you want to wait until it will be visible do this:

```
# waits 3 seconds until first element will be visible    
WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((elements[0])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **code** particularly this **css selector** :

```
visibilty =  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.ra22>div:first-child").is_displayed()
print(visibilty)
```

Then you can have **conditions** as per the status of visibilty  variable.